# How to easily get nth String character in Elixir?

Tags: string, elixir

In Ruby, I can easily get nth element of a string by `"Hello"[0] #=> "H"`.

I am aware of `String.slice/3` in Elixir and I can do it this way: `String.slice("Hello", 0..0)`. This method seems a little verbose though, is there a shorter way to get nth element of string in Elixir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the nth grapheme as a String, you can use `String.at/2`:

```
iex(1)> String.at "hello", 2
"l"
iex(2)> String.at "πr²", 2
"²"
```

To get the nth byte as an integer, you can use `:binary.at/2`:

```
iex(3)> :binary.at "hello", 2
108
iex(4)> <<108>>
"l"
iex(5)> :binary.at "πr²", 2
114
iex(6)> <<114>>
"r"
```